# If $f$ is a null function and $|g|≤|f |$, then $g$ is a null function.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Definition:** A function $f$ is a null function if $~\int |f|=0$.
In this definition we assume the integrability of $~|f|~$ but we are
not assuming that $f$ is integrable.
Now I have the problem with understating the following theorem.

**Theorem:** If $f$ is a null function and $|g|≤|f |$, then $g$ is a null function.
[image]

Now the problems in understanding the theorem are:
$(1)$ Why we need to show $g$ is integrable? Since by definition we have to show $\int |g|=0$ whenever $\int |f|=0$. There is no required of showing the integrability of $g$  I think. But I am wrong and why?
$(2)$ Since $|g|\le |f|,~~$ why we cannot integrate both side and conclude $\int |g|=0~?$
$(3)$ How can I write $g \simeq |f|+|f|+\cdots,$ when by hypothesis we already have $|g|\le |f|?$
Please help me to understand this theorem. Thank you!

**Note:** A real valued function $f$ can be written as $~f\simeq \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ if $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int |f_n|<\infty~$ and $~f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)~$ for all $~x \in \mathbb R$ whenever $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n(x)|<\infty$.

Comment: What does $\simeq$ mean in this context? My guess is that $g\simeq |f|+|f|+\ldots $ will then imply that $g$ (and hence $|g|$) is measurable because $|f|$ is measurable. As the proof states, this is the only difficulty because after you prove this, then you can conclude $0\leq\int|g|\leq\int|f|=0$.